# Different GPO behaviour between Windows Server 2008 and Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, group-policy

In Windows Server 2008 I was able to create a GPO with both Computer configuration and User configuration.
This GPO I put in the OU of that certain group of computers.
When an Authenticated user would log on on this computer (An user that is located in an other OU), both the Computer configuration and the User configuration would be applied.

Now with our new domain (we migrated to a new name), we have a Windows server 2012. Here I'm trying to do the same thing.
I created the same GPO with both Computer configuration and User configuration.
When I place this GPO only in the OU of that certain group of computers and an authenticated user logs on, only the Computer configuration part of the GPO is being applied.
I only get the User configuration part to work when I also place the GPO in the OU where the user is located.

But unfortunately this means that that GPO (the user config part) is also applied when the same user logs on to a different computers.
I know this can be resolved with delegation, but I was wondering what could be the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable User Loopback Policy Processing.

Computer > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Group Policy

Configure User group policy loopback processing mode

Comment: AFAIK Windows 2008 behaved in the same way with regards to the need for loopback processing in this scenario, so I guess something else changed in the OP's setup as well as the upgrade to 2012.